# Referencing a custom field id

Tags: salesforce, apex, custom-object

I have two custom objects, Category and Case, I set category as parent. Column Category_ID in category is referenced by custom object Case. I executed two queries in developer console

> SELECT Category_ID__c,id, Name FROM Category__c
>   SELECT Category_ID__c,id, Name FROM Case__c
>   and I found out the value of Category_ID in Case was like 'a0D'F000001MmjUae' and 'a0D'F000001MmjUde',yet in Category it's '0' and '1'.

**VisualPage**

```
          <apex:outputLabel value="Category" />  
             <apex:selectList value="{!categoryType}" size="1">
             <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}"/>
             </apex:selectList>             

             <apex:outputLabel value="Case" />  
               <apex:selectList value="{!caseId}" size="1">
               <apex:selectOptions value="{!items2}"/>
             </apex:selectList>   


//From here is Controller


   public String categoryType{set;get;}

   public List<SelectOption> getItems(){
        List<selectoption> mlst = new List<selectoption>();
        for(VirtualCaseCategory__c m: [SELECT Category_ID__c, Name FROM VirtualCaseCategory__c]){
            mlst.add(new selectoption(m.Id,m.Name));
        }
        return mlst;
    }  
     public List<SelectOption> getItems2(){
        List<selectoption> mlst = new List<selectoption>();

        for(VirtualCaseCases__c m: [SELECT Category_ID__c, Name FROM VirtualCaseCases__c WHERE Category_ID__c =:categoryType]){
            mlst.add(new selectoption(m.Id,m.Name));
        }
        return mlst;
    }
```

I want to get different Case selectList based on selected `Category_ID` value.
Anyone can tell me why? Because I want to run some queries based on the same `Category_ID` value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're not adding `Category_Id__c` in `selectList` using `for` loop.

```
for(VirtualCaseCategory__c m: [SELECT Category_ID__c, Name FROM VirtualCaseCategory__c]){
            // insert Category_ID__c in the select option
            mlst.add(new selectoption(m.Category_ID__c,m.Name));
        }
```

Same is the case with other `for` loop

```
for(VirtualCaseCases__c m: [SELECT Category_ID__c, Name FROM VirtualCaseCases__c WHERE Category_ID__c =:categoryType]){
            // Same here as well
            mlst.add(new selectoption(m.Category_ID__c,m.Name));
        }
```